# Using local storage with Kendo UI

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, local-storage

I'm trying to save some settings to localStorage using Kendo UI. I've my code setup like this:

```
 settings: {
      getSettings: function () {
            console.log("reading settings");
            console.log("localStorage.getItem('chkEnergy') = " + localStorage.getItem('chkEnergy'));
            console.log("this.get('chkEnergy) = " + this.get('chkEnergy'));
            this.set('chkEnergy', localStorage.getItem('chkEnergy'));
            this.set('chkSleep', localStorage.getItem('chkSleep'));
            this.set('chkActivity', localStorage.getItem('chkActivity'));
            this.set('notifications', localStorage.getItem('notifications'));
            this.set('notification_interval', localStorage.getItem('notification_interval'));
        },
        saveSettings: function () {
            console.log("writing settings");
            console.log("this.get('chkEnergy) = " + this.get('chkEnergy'));
            localStorage.setItem('chkEnergy', this.get('chkEnergy'));
            localStorage.setItem('chkSleep', this.get('chkSleep'));
            localStorage.setItem('chkActivity', this.get('chkActivity'));
            localStorage.setItem('notifications', this.get('notifications'));
            localStorage.setItem('notification_interval', this.get('notification_interval'));

        },
        chkEnergy: localStorage.getItem('chkEnergy'),
        chkSleep: localStorage.getItem('chkSleep'),
        chkActivity: localStorage.getItem('chkActivity'),
        notifications: false,
        notification_interval: 1,
        intervals: [{
                'IntName': '1. time',
                'value': '1'
            },
            {
                'IntName': '2. timer',
                'value': '2'
            },
            {
                'IntName': '3. timer',
                'value': '3'
            },
            {
                'IntName': '4. timer',
                'value': '4'
            }]}
```

and my View is:

```
<div data-role="view" data-layout="main" data-model="APP.models.settings" >
    <div data-role="notification" id="ntf"></div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
        <li>Indstillinger
            <ul>
                <li>Påmindelser
                    <input data-role="switch" id="switchNotification" data-on-label="til" data-off-label="fra" data-bind="checked: notifications, events: { change: setNotifications }" />
                </li>
                <li>Interval
                    <input data-role="dropdownlist" id="notificationgap" data-theme="silver" data-text-field="IntName" data-value-field="value" data-bind="value: notification_interval,
                          source: intervals,
                          events: {
                          change: setNotifications
                          },
                          enabled: notifications" style="width:5em">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Spørgsmål
            <ul>
                <li>Træthed
                    <input data-role="switch" data-on-label="til" data-off-label="fra" data-bind="checked: chkEnergy, events: { change: saveSettings }" />
                </li>
                <li>Søvn
                    <input data-role="switch" data-on-label="til" data-off-label="fra" data-bind="checked: chkSleep, events: { change: saveSettings }" />
                </li>
                <li>Aktivitet
                    <input data-role="switch" data-on-label="til" data-off-label="fra" data-bind="checked: chkActivity, events: { change: saveSettings }" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <a data-role="button" data-bind="events: { click: getSettings }">Click me</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but for some reason this.get('chkEnergy') is a delayed value. It ios as if the value is not changed until after the "change" event has completed. why?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to listen for change in the kendo observable like so:

```
window.APP.models.settings.bind("change",window.APP.models.settings.saveSettings);
```